# What do you call a function with boolean inputs, but a non-boolean result?

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus

What do you call a function like $f:\{0,1\}^n→\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$?

I'm trying to learn about [logic minimization](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_optimization) in order to build an optimization pass for a compiler, but all the techniques I've found are focused on functions with boolean input *and* output.

Algorithms like Quine–McCluskey seem to generalize straightforwardly, and I imagine that most heuristics will too, but I want to be sure there's not a whole body of thought that I'm missing.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I would call it a function ;-)

Comment: I would call it a function with Boolean inputs and a non Boolean result. Presumably you are dealing with `x`s (don't cares)?

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I am not dealing with "don't cares", but a larger range of outcomes. I've edited my question to clarify a bit.